# What is the best way to build folders compact tree?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, sqlite, database-schema

I'm making a browser of defined list of files.
I want to compact empty folders (Like idea based IDE usally can do)

Originally I have a list of files (I get it from MediaStore):

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.mp3
folder1/folder2/folder3/file2.mp3
folder1/file3.mp3
```

And I want my browser has this structure:

```
folder1
       -folder2/folder3
                      -file1.mp3
                      -file2.mp3
       -file3.mp3
```

---

How I did that:

When the first time I get files from MediaStore I create a table in a database:

```
id name parent_id has_songs
0  folder1 -1 1
1  folder2 0 0
2  folder3 1 1
```

When every time the browser displays folders it makes a request to the database.
And then I start checking folders inside(An additional request to the db for every check is needed): if a folder doesn't have songs and has only one child folder then compact them, then check the next and the next.

This way for the example above if I want to see 'insides' of folder1 it does 3 requests to the local db:

```
1. Get list of all folders (Make a request to the db here)
2. Check folder2 has one subfolder and doesn't have songs (Make a request to the db here)
3. Check folder3 has one subfolder and doesn't have songs (Make a request to the db here)
```

**1. Is that the best way to implement this?**

**2. Is it performance critical
    to make so many requests to the local db on user click?**

Comment: You can see this library: https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView

Comment: @licon Using this lib changes nothing, anyway I have to do the same requests to a database to inflate the library tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your environment. :)

**In general:**
If the file list is relatively small it is worth to consider if you could keep all the information in memory. If you have enough free memory, this could be the best solution since it is way faster than reaching the database. I used to create an object that actually represents the directory and file structure, afterwards the view side opend and closed the blocks according to user demands. (Open all, close all etc.)

**Is that the best way to implement this?**
The environment is the key. As I mentioned it could be a good solution. If you are using a distant (or more advanced [[SQLite is able to do it]](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)) database server it is also a good thing to consider to create a view which contains the child count. (Or simply change the generated table introducing the "inside_dir_count" field.) This way you could fetch entire paths.

**Is it performance critical to make so many requests to the local db on user click?**
It is a relative small request to the database you represented here, and if it really depends on the click of the user it is a good solution. The mentioned local database should respond in little to no time. This action is not something that will happen 1000 times per second, so in my personal view it is good solution but there is a room for improvement like in everything.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. I asked this question in case I made a huge mistake and didn't see that. Now I have more confidence about my decision.